# Complex Sort Function using Join, SQL, Order Categories by Products' expiry, Opencart

Tags: php, sql, sorting, opencart

**UPDATE**

My end goal was to sort categories by the expiry dates of the products within. So the category with a product closest to expiring goes first, categories with all products expired go last. Thanks to Greg, see the complete answer at the bottom of the question.

**/UPDATE**

This works fine except for the second line (SELECT MIN(date_expires... Any ideas on how to rewrite this line?

```
 SELECT   c.category_id, 
          name, 
          c.image, 
          description,
          (SELECT MIN(date_expires) 
           FROM     product 
           WHERE date_expires >= NOW() AND 
                 p.product_id = p2c.product_id) AS expiring
FROM category c 
        LEFT JOIN category_description cd 
            ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c 
            ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN product p 
            ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
WHERE c.parent_id = 0 AND c.status = '1'
GROUP BY c.category_id
ORDER BY expiring
```

Some sample data:

```
category:
category_id = 62
category_id = 64
category_id = 63

product_to_category:
product_id = 43 category_id = 62
product_id = 50 category_id = 63
product_id = 56 category_id = 63
product_id = 58 category_id = 62
product_id = 59 category_id = 63
product_id = 60 category_id = 63
product_id = 61 category_id = 63
product_id = 62 category_id = 63
product_id = 63 category_id = 64

product:
product_id = 43 date_expires = 2012-07-11 20:35:00
product_id = 50 date_expires = 2012-06-29 00:00:00
product_id = 56 date_expires = 2012-07-13 00:00:00
product_id = 58 date_expires = 2012-07-26 15:01:00
product_id = 59 date_expires = 2012-07-16 14:12:00
product_id = 60 date_expires = 2012-07-18 08:15:00
product_id = 61 date_expires = 2012-08-02 13:04:00
product_id = 62 date_expires = 2012-08-24 00:00:00
product_id = 63 date_expires = 2012-07-12 19:16:00
```

**ANSWER**
My end goal was to get

```
SELECT c.category_id, minDateExpires.Expiring, 
CASE WHEN Expiring > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as available 
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id)   
LEFT JOIN product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)   
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT MIN(date_expires) AS expiring, category_id FROM product p join product_to_category p2c on p2c.product_id = p.product_id WHERE date_expires >= GETDATE() GROUP BY category_id
) minDateExpires on p2c.category_id = minDateExpires.category_id
ORDER BY available, expiring
```

If you are looking for this for **OpenCart** in particular and you are using the Categories module then go to catalog/model/catalog/category.php and edit function getCategoriesPag() to:

```
    public function getCategoriesPag($data) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT c.category_id, name, c.image, description, minDateExpires.Expiring, CASE WHEN Expiring > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as available FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(date_expires) AS expiring, category_id FROM product p JOIN product_to_category p2c on p2c.product_id = p.product_id WHERE date_expires >= NOW() GROUP BY category_id) minDateExpires on p2c.category_id = minDateExpires.category_id WHERE c.parent_id = 0 AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'  AND c.status = '1' GROUP BY c.category_id ORDER BY available, Expiring, c.sort_order");

        return $query->rows;
    }
```

You will need to add your own date_expires field to the database and to your back end admin panel.

Comment: What doesn't work about the problem line?  Do you get some kind of error?  What have you tried?  And is this supposed to be DBMS agnostic, or is it targeted at a specific DBMS?

Comment: @Jim Hey not sure what DBMS is, it's a search from a PHP based site on Opencart. I don't get an error, but I also don't get any results from that particular line. I've tried everything I can think of with this approach and by usines CASE, neither to any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE TO ANSWER NOW THAT DATA SAMPLES ARE AVAILABLE

Still assuming it's Microsoft SQL Server, this query produces the following result

```
SELECT c.category_id, minDateExpires.Expiring 
FROM category c   
LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id)   
LEFT JOIN product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)   
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT MIN(date_expires) AS expiring, Product_ID FROM product WHERE date_expires >= GETDATE() GROUP BY Product_ID 
) minDateExpires on p.product_id = minDateExpires.product_id 
ORDER BY expiring
```

Results:

```
category_id Expiring
63      NULL
63      NULL
62      NULL
64      NULL
63      2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
63      2012-07-18 08:15:00.000
62      2012-07-26 15:01:00.000
63      2012-08-02 13:04:00.000
63      2012-08-24 00:00:00.000
```

The null columns are there because there is no min date for those product id's >= the current date/time. Are you actually after the minimum date time grouped by categoryid, not product id? In which case your query could be something like:

```
SELECT c.category_id, minDateExpires.Expiring
FROM @category c
LEFT JOIN @product_to_category p2c ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id)   
LEFT JOIN @product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)   
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT MIN(date_expires) AS expiring, Category_ID FROM @product p join @product_to_category p2c on p2c.product_id = p.product_id WHERE date_expires >= GETDATE() GROUP BY Category_id
) minDateExpires on p2c.category_id = minDateExpires.category_id
ORDER BY expiring
```

which gives you

```
64  NULL
63  2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
63  2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
63  2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
63  2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
63  2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
63  2012-07-16 14:12:00.000
62  2012-07-26 15:01:00.000
62  2012-07-26 15:01:00.000
```

Comment: Wow this is impressive stuff thanks. There is an extra bracket going on in the subquery though and this is way too far over my head.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to take out the last bracket there. Updating now

Comment: Hmm it's still not bringing results for me. I tried changing the first 'minDateExpires.Expiring' to 'minDateExpires.expiring' and then I also tried changing 'ORDER BY minDateExpires.expiring' and neither worked...

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just no results? If it's just no results then you'll need to provide some sample data

Comment: No error. I updated the question so you can get a better idea of the data and be able to see the final result (website)

Comment: I assumed grouping it by category would be best because I am using a foreach ($categories as $category) to output the results. I just have to head out for a bit I'll give this a try when I get back. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this statement is true:

> The original problem lies in the fact that the sub query cannot see the tables you joined to in the main query. So p.product_id and p2c.product_id do not exist in the sub query.

Since that condition is part of an outer join in the main query, that condition is already known to be true or will evaluate to null and thereby cause a null result. Now your sample data suggests you don't need outer joins anyway and I can see that there are expiration dates into the future on many of the rows.

I believe you meant to write this as your subquery. It might be worth a try even though some of the other info we've got suggests it still won't quite be the final solution.

```
(
SELECT MIN(date_expires) 
FROM product as p2
WHERE date_expires >= NOW() AND 
      p2.product_id = p.product_id
) AS expiring
```

**EDIT**
Make the change I just suggested, but also get rid of the GROUP BY clause.

**EDIT 2**

**1)** You seem to have attributes in multiple tables that might belong in a single product table. I'll assume that you have good reasons for that.

**2)** Mysql allows you to mix aggregate and non-aggregate columns, but that is a bad practice and if my theory proves true, that was a big part of the reason we were all stumped for a little while.

**3)** All of the left outer joins seem be doing what you'd normally use an inner join for. You won't regret doing this right the first time.

**4)** The expiration date can be looked up via a subquery the way you first wrote it or as another join as done by the other answer. If there is really a one-to-one relationship there, then MIN() and GROUP BY are not necessary and may confuse somebody. (In fact, see edit #3.)

**5)** Since your subquery evaluates as null for any product with an expiration falling in the past, you may need to ORDER BY a second column or just use the expiration date regardless of whether it's past or future.

**EDIT 3**

```
SELECT
    c.category_id,
    MIN(name) as name,
    c.image /* better as a subquery if you can't do an aggregate on a LOB */
    MIN(c.description) as description,

    /* don't even need the subquery because you've already joined the product table */
    CASE
        WHEN MIN(p.date_expires) >= NOW() THEN MIN(p.date_expires)
        ELSE NULL /* this may not be what you really wanted */
    END as expiring_my_first_guess,

    /* what was really intended */
    MIN( CASE WHEN p.date_expires >= NOW() THEN p.date_expires ELSE NULL END ) as expiring,

FROM category c 
    INNER JOIN category_description cd 
        ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
    INNER JOIN product_to_category p2c 
        ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id) 
    INNER JOIN JOIN product p 
        ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
WHERE c.parent_id = 0 AND c.status = '1'
GROUP BY c.category_id
ORDER BY expiring
```

Comment: I think your GROUP BY is messing it up. Try getting rid of it. And that probably means you're using mysql, btw.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense I used the GROUP BY just because I thought I would have to. I am using a foreach ($categories as $category) to output the results. I will try your suggestions in a couple of hours thanks for the input!

Comment: you're right, you can keep the current sub-select. Not sure what I was thinking there. I still prefer joining to a sub select rather than having it in the select, but both work. Agree about getting rid of the group by

Comment: Actually, I think I understand now. You do want the GROUP BY. This is a subquery that returns the min expire date for product in a category: MIN( (SELECT date_expires FROM product as p2 WHERE p2.product_id = p2c.product_id) ) as expiring. Use the join because it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: And I'm making myself look silly because I didn't realize you had already joined the product table. There's no reason for a subquery at all.

Comment: Why the MIN(name) and MIN(description)? 'WHEN MIN(p.date_expires) >= NOW() THEN' will return an entire category as expired if just one of it's products are. I want it to return expired if all products within the category are expired. As for GROUP BY product, it will list a category once for each product it has. I totally agree with your other points though.

Comment: I think this article has a good summary of the issue with [grouping and aggregates](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/03/10/mysql-standard-group-by/). We had no clear insight into your desired sort until the latest edits. I still don't believe that you quite how groupings work though, but I'm glad you got something to work for you.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. I made sure to upvote you because your answer was really helpful and expanded my knowledge. Thanks again for your time